# Lucas Numbers have the same prime divisors?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, number-theory

Let $L_n$ be the $n$ th Lucas number, with $$L_0 = 2, L_1=1, L_{n+1} = L_n + L_{n-1}$$
Is it true that for every even number $n \geq 4$, if the number $L_n - 2$ has a prime divisor $p > 2$, then the number $L_{n+1} - 1$ is also divided by $p$? If not, then is the statement still correct with $n = 2018$? If not, how many number $n$ satisfy that if the number $L_n - 2$ has a prime divisor $p > 2$, then the number $L_{n+1} - 1$ is also divided by $p$?

(Sorry, English is my second language)

Comment: What makes you believe this is true? What have you tried?

Comment: @MeesdeVries : I tried with $n = 4, 6, 8$, and they are correct. The original problem is with $n = 2018$, however since the statement holds with $n = 4, 6$ then I believe this is true?

Comment: @apple The Strong Law of Small Numbers...;)